# How do I pull specific text from one document into a new one using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I have been tasked with writing an XSLT script to convert data from one file into a new format. My XSLT knowledge is very limited so I'm hoping I can get some help here. I need to copy the text inside the quotes of the `exhibit path=` line of the text below:

```
<unit>
   <chapter>
        <exhibit path="chapter001/t01_reader00.html"/>
   </chapter>
   <chapter>
        <exhibit path="chapter001/chapter01_reader01.html"/>
        <exhibit path="chapter001/chapter01_reader02.html"/>
   </chapter>
</unit>
```

And have it output to the new file into the `href=` field so it appears like it does below:

```
<item href="chapter001/chapter01_reader01.html" />
<item href="chapter001/chapter01_reader02.html" />
```

This is what I've tried but I know it's way off.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="pub-id" version="3.0">
            <manifest>
                <xsl:template match="/">
                    <item>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="//chapter" />
                    </item>
                </xsl:template>
            </manifest> 
        </package>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? With a basic understanding of XSLT this should be doable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it simply like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//exhibit"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="exhibit">
    <item href="{@path}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ4Z

Answer (score 0):

You can try this XSLT-1.0 code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="package" namespace-uri="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
            <xsl:attribute name="unique-identifier">pub-id</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="version">3.0</xsl:attribute>
            <manifest>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//exhibit" />
            </manifest> 
        </xsl:element>     
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="exhibit">
        <xsl:element name="item">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="@path" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>"
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="pub-id" version="3.0">
  <manifest>
    <item href="chapter001/t01_reader00.html"/>"
    <item href="chapter001/chapter01_reader01.html"/>"
    <item href="chapter001/chapter01_reader02.html"/>"
  </manifest>
</package>
```

Notice, that all elements are in the default namespace "http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf".